# Why doesn't sorting work for an iterator in Map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, range-based-loop

So here is my code; I find the sort doesn't work for the vector in this map. Does anyone know why?

The output of this code is still "3 1 2 4 5"

```
map<int, vector<int> > values;
values[1] = {3,1,2,4,5};
for(auto g: values) {
    sort(g.second.begin(), g.second.end());
}
for(int i=0;i<values[1].size();i++) {
    cout<<values[1][i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Change `auto g` for `auto& g` to find out :-) [demo](https://ideone.com/sEAZDj)

Comment: Also, consider using a range-for loop for the `cout` loop as well: `for(auto value : values[1]) { cout << value << " "; }`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a referenced type in the range based for loop

```
for(auto &g: values) {
    sort(g.second.begin(), g.second.end());
}
```

Otherwise the range based for loop deals with copies of elements stored in the map.

If your compiler supports the C++ 17 you can also write

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

for (auto &[key, v] : values)
{
    std::sort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`auto g: values` takes **the value of** an element of `values` but does not allow you to change the contents in `values`.

`auto &g: values` takes **a reference to** an element of `values` which allows you to change the contents of `values`